# BigQuery command line load error

Tags: google-bigquery

The BQ command line load command fails occasionally with the error trace mentioned below:

In the log I get the details:
If this problem persists, you may have encountered a bug in the bigquery client.
Google engineers monitor and answer questions on Stack Overflow, with the tag
google-bigquery:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?tags=google-bigquery
Please include a brief description of the steps that led to this issue, as well
as the information attached to the file at http://goo.gl/7YJHmH

Answer (score 1):

Try removing `--replace` and make sure the `<destination_table>` does not exist. You can later delete the previous table. Or similarly, flip the operations; delete the table first before loading the new table.